# How to draw an 'x' in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

To draw an ellipse in Qt, we can simply go `QGraphicsScene->addEllipse();`

Is there an equivalent method to draw an 'x'?  And when redrawing a scene, how would you delete said 'x' (say, to move it)?

Comment: would this not be drawing two lines at an angle?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Never even noticed that :)  I've drawn some points with the ellipse, and am drawing the crosses as "destination" points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [QGraphicsScene::addSimpleText(const QString &text, const QFont &font=QFont())](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#id-077c9041-5f7b-44c3-ab70-559badb26c8e) to draw the letter "x".

Comment: Updated link: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addSimpleText